# Electronic tachometer over reads

Tags: analog, tachometer

The electronic analog tachometer on my small boat diesel has recently started to overread on startup of the engine (e.g. it reads 2000 rpm on idle).  After about 5 - 10 minutes it drops back quite suddenly to more realistic figures (about 750 rpm on idle, and about 2250 at cruising speed, both of which are probably not far off the truth). I don't have a fitted voltmeter, but do have a portable multimeter, though accessing the batteries whilst the engine is running is difficult. System is 12 VDC, and for the engine electrics, common negative via the engine block. Grateful for any advice - e.g. instrument failing or alternator failing etc.

Comment: Need to know the type of electronic metering. Optical? Magnetic? ??

Comment: there's a lead to the alternator.  I always assumed (schoolboyl physics level electronic knowledge) that the tacho counts the  unrectified pulses from the alternator by capacitance. But it is not optical, for sure, and I don't think it's magnetic.

Comment: Can you confirm it is the meter and not the engine that is at 2000 RPM on startup.

Answer (score 1):

The analog tachs I've used have a calibration switch and potentiometer accesible on the back.  Over time the contacts in the switch and pot get dirty or corroded, causing the meter to read high.  To fix this, use a small screwdriver to move the switch and pot back and forth a few times to scrape off thte corrosion.  The pot may be hidden behind a rubber plug.

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a go.  Need to find the manual!!